# Drupal - link to node only (no header, side bar, etc)

Tags: drupal

In Drupal can I create a link to just a node, so not the node page with the header, side bars, footer, etc. So the page is literally just the node's contence, no css files or anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your theme create a page-node-1.tpl.php file. In that file just print $content;

```
<?php print $content; ?>
```

now when you navigate to node/1 of your site you will not have anything else but the content of the node. What ever you need to add you can add around that.

Answer (score 0):

Hum not rely, what are you trying to do? If you want to expose some data to an other service use the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module for that, you can create a REST / Soap web service based on Drupal to expose your content.

Comment: Actually it was a lightbox issue where I wanted a node in a lightbox and by default it was loading the entire node page. Ive got round it with views, perhaps a bit overkill but its working. Thanks